Monitor LXC/CT metrics using opentelemetry-collector
Running a CT(LXC) on my Proxmox host, I can see the proper CPU&RAM limits and usage using htop in the shell, but opentelemetry-collector, using the hostmetrics reciever, is showing me the proxmox node ram & cpu usage.
Do you know of a way to start the otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib image within my LXC that would let it "see" only the allocated RAM & CPU as does htop ?
In short, my pve has 64GB or RAM, the LXC #100 has 4GB allocated, otel is running inside docker and has no explicit ram limit, today otel is telling me 64GB of available RAM instead of 4GB...
I know running the docker image of otel within an LXC is a double containerization, but hey, could still maybe make it work :D
tried node-exporter and same issue it sees the entire node, not only the LXC it's running in...
